# How to create a page that updates with a HTML form from another page without a database?

Tags: javascript, html

This is what I'm looking for. I can't figure out how to code this and have read through many other similar problems.

What I want is a master page to update another without a database and without using PHP. This is because I don't have access to such resources as this is a side project for work I'm doing on my own time.

This is how I was planning it in my head.

Form page would have 2 radio buttons per title. Which represents Go and Stop. A user would select either radio buttons and submit the form.

Display page would display the Title and the selected image corresponding to that Radio button selected. It would also have to be updated when the page content changes when a new update is submitted from the form page. This page will be visible to multiple users and updates to all users.

So what I would like to know if this is possible or if I have to get more access to develop a database and run PHP.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: exactly how would this "display page" be able to know when a new radio button setting had been submitted? You'd need to store **SOMETHING** on the server to indicate which radio button had been selected. Whether that's a database or a simple flat file or a memcached key=value, whatever, you'd still need something that effective acts as a very specific single-value database storage system anyways.

Comment: "submit" is an incorrect term when there is no server at all. perhaps "on click". Also, no one outside the own browser will see any update that only happens there.

Comment: Thanks, I think I've figured it out. I will try using PHP with a csv or txt file. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say "without a database and without using php", it sounds like you actually mean "without any sort of server-side scripting"; i.e., only using HTML and JavaScript, so that you can just use a simple static HTTP file server on the backend.

This is impossible if the *actions* of one user must affect the *state* of another user (i.e. what they see on the webpage) such as in the scenario you described:

1. User A loads the main page, and sees image 1.
2. User B loads the secondary page, chooses "2" from the dropdown, and submits form.
3. User A re-loads the main page, and sees image 2.

If only one user were involved, you could get away with using javascript cookies or localstorage. The scenario you describe requires that User B's action must be communicated to User A in the form of a new state. Each user's client (browser) only knows how to communicate with the server. The clients have no mechanism to communicate directly with each other. Therefore, the server must store state and provide an endpoint for changing state.

In my opinion, the *fastest and easiest* way to crank out a proof-of-concept server for the requirements you describe is to use [python flask](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/). For a quick demo, you can eschew the database and just use a global variable. If you decide you want a database, [sqlite3](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) is already included with a standard python installation. It's extremely lightweight, flexible, and fantastic for prototyping.

---

Here is a full python flask demo server that does what you're trying to accomplish. You would use this *instead* of your usual HTTP server.

**server.py**

```
from flask import Flask, escape, request, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)
image = '1'

@app.route('/')
def main():
    global image

    return render_template('index.html', image=image)

@app.route('/config/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def config():
    global image

    if request.method == 'POST':
        image = request.form['image']

    return render_template('config.html', image=image)
```

**templates/index.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Main Page</title>
<img src="/static/{{ image }}.jpg" alt="image" />
```

**templates/config.html**

```
<!doctype html>
<title>Config Page</title>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="radio" name="image" value="1">
  <input type="radio" name="image" value="2">
  <input type="submit" value="save">
</form>
```

Here is the full directory structure.

```
├── server.py
├── static
│   ├── 1.jpg
│   └── 2.jpg
└── templates
    ├── config.html
    └── index.html
```

To install flask:

```
pip install flask
```

To run the server (run this from the same directory where `server.py` is stored):

```
FLASK_APP=server.py flask run
```

To view the webpages:

```
http://localhost:5000/
http://localhost:5000/config/
```

Comment: Hi, so if I created a txt file and stored that on the same directory I should still be able to use PHP?

Comment: sure, but you'll have to write the code to store and read the data by hand. and it's a huge potential security hole.

Comment: @user1557936 so, uhhh... six years late, but i've re-written this answer. same conclusion, but a little more context and an example of how to achieve this effect with, like, a dozen lines of python code.